# Using ActionView::TestCase::Behavior and the view method in a presenter spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, presenter, viewcontext

Using the Railscast example, I have written a spec for my presenter which includes `ActionView::TestCase::Behavior` and passes in the `view` method to the presenter.

`spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
  ... 
  config.include ActionView::TestCase::Behavior, :example_group => {:file_path => %r{spec/presenters}}
  ...
```

`spec/presenters/order_presenter_spec.rb`:

```
  require 'spec_helper'

  describe OrderPresenter do

    describe "#subtotal" do
      subject { OrderPresenter.new(order, view).subtotal }

      let(:order) { stub(:order, working_subtotal: 4500) }

      it "renders the subtotal table row" do
        should == "<tr><th>SUBTOTAL</th><td>$45.00</td></tr>"
      end
    end
  end
```

However, this gave me two errors. 
The first was

```
  /Users/shevaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:12:in `block in <module:TemplateAssertions>': undefined method `setup' for #<Class:0x007fe2343b2f40> (NoMethodError)
```

so I included `ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown` in the same way as `ActionView::TestCase::Behavior`.

Fixing that gave me the error:

```
  NoMethodError:
   undefined method `view_context' for nil:NilClass
```

when calling `view`. This is caused by the `@controller` instance variable inside `ActionView::TestCase` being `nil`.

I am using Rails 3.2.13 and rspec-rails 2.13.0 and have another application using the same versions which *just works*.

The only thing I can think of that might make a difference is that this app is using MongoDB so maybe the ActiveRecord application includes something which sets up  `@controller` for free?

I have got a workaround which makes the presenter specs pass, but I would like to know how `@controller` normally gets instantiated, and if there's a more elegant way to do this for a MongoDB project (if it is ActiveRecord that's doing the magic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My current solution is to instantiate the `@controller` instance variable by calling `setup_with_controller` before the presenter specs.

`spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown, :example_group => {:file_path => %r{spec/presenters}}

  config.include ActionView::TestCase::Behavior, :example_group => {:file_path => %r{spec/presenters}}

  config.before(:each, example_group: {:file_path => %r{spec/presenters}}) do
    setup_with_controller  # this is necessary because otherwise @controller is nil, but why?
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: You are my hero, there is nothing anywhere else that helps with this issue. Have you found the root cause?

Comment: Note that in some later version of Rspec, `example_group` is no longer necessary. Cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369127/rspec-3-deprecation-warning-filtering-by-an-example-group-subhash-is-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You can also create your own view:

```
let(:view) { ActionController::Base.new.view_context }
subject { OrderPresenter.new(order, view).subtotal }
```

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2922913#1029887