# Rspec 3 Deprecation Warning: Filtering by an example_group subhash is deprecated. Use the subhash to filter directly instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When running my Rspec version 3 tests, I get the following deprecation warnings:

Filtering by an `:example_group` subhash is deprecated. Use the subhash to filter directly instead. Called from /path/to/file.rb:6:in `block in '.

Filtering by an `:example_group` subhash is deprecated. Use the subhash to filter directly instead. Called from /path/to/file.rb:8:in `block in '.

From path/to/file.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  module MyCodeHelpers
   #
  end

  config.include MyCodeHelpers, example_group: { :file_path => %r(spec/services/my_code) }

  config.before(:all, example_group: { :file_path => %r(spec/services/my_code) }) do
    @stub = true
  end
end
```

Does this simply mean removing the 'example_group: {}' around the :file_path value (see below)?

```
config.include MyCodeHelpers, :file_path => %r(spec/services/my_code)
```

and

```
config.before(:all, :file_path => %r(spec/services/my_code)) do
  @stub = true
end
```

Comment: Thank you for both answers. As Frederick indicated, making the changes shown above did take care of the deprecation warnings (I just wasn't sure what the ramifications were). Micharch54, if I were doing individual examples (instead of a folder of files), that would be the way to go. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what it's saying. It applies both when you are setting metadata and when you are using the metadata, either by querying it or using it to filter a `config.include`

For a full explanation of why, see [this commit](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/f3ec09fd2441775c8f73e62b70c4589f5aca0c40) but in a nutshell they thought it was confusing for an example group's metadata to have a key `example_group` when that hash only has metadata for the example group